# Apache mod_proxy, how to forward request into local network ip(server)

Tags: mod-proxy

Can't figure out, how to configure mod_proxy for this.

I have two domains, one is working fine at the moment. Second is bind to the same ip.

I need to forward requests from second domain to another server in local network.

like that:

```
domain1.com => 192.168.1.101
domain2.com => 192.168.1.102
```

What configuration or directives i should use?

Thanks ;)

**Update**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/domain1/public"
        ServerName www.domain1.com
        <Directory />
        </Directory>
        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/opt/lampp/cgi-bin/"
        CustomLog  /opt/lampp/logs/custom_apache.log common
        ErrorLog /opt/lampp/logs/error_apache.log
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName www.domain2.com
 ProxyRequests Off
 ProxyPreserveHost On
 <Proxy *>
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
 </Proxy>
 ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.103:8080/
 ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.103:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

It just doesn't redirect to second server. That's it. And when i restart apache, it says something with overlapping 80 port.

```
[warn] _default_ VirtualHost overlap on port 80, the first has precedence
```

I guess something should be changed next to VirtualHost, in place of *(all), should be domain name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably this thread has a answer of your query
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664287/redirect-url-path-to-forward-to-tomcat-servlet-using-apache-mod-proxy

Comment: hmm didn't worked for me :\

Comment: In what way didn't it work? What did you do, what happened exactly? Were there error messages in the browser or in the logs?

Comment: i think you need two virtual host entry, one for domain1 and one for domain 2

Comment: also configuration file has virualhost defined somewhere else, that's why you are getting warning

Comment: Sorry were a bit busy. I have updated post.

Answer (score 0):

You need to uncomment or specify the NameVirtualHost *:80 config verb before your virtualhosts declarations, otherwise it will only ever use one container.